# arm64-v8a type OS Architecture device for Android device not working

Tags: android, mupdf

From the last couple of days, I stuck in implementing MuPDF in android. It supports only

1 . armeabi-v7a
2 . armeabi
3 . mips
4 . x86

Not working in arm64-v8a type OS Architecture device.

PDF required opening within the APP
Can anyone help me out to find any alternate solution for it? 
if needed any more information please let me know.

Comment: What's in the jinLibs folder??

Answer (score 0):

you can compile the binary yourself

follow the guide on the official site:

http://mupdf.com/docs/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android

then make the following changes to

```
..<mupdf_src>/platform/android/view/jni/Application.mk file
```

set the follwing variables:

```
APP_PLATFORM=android-21
APP_ABI := arm64-v8a
```

make sure you have the latest android ndk from here:

```
https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html
```

under your **./ndk directory/toolchains**

look for the number after all packages
for example mine was

```
aarch64-linux-android-4.9
```

then in Application.mk on the last line add the following:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9
```

then do the ndk-build

now you should have the so file for arm64-v8a under libs directory.